# Can't invoke method with SignalR

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app and I use signalr, I am able to connect to the hub, but it is not possible to invoke a method, every time I get this exception:`Unhandled Exception: type 'GeneralError' is not a subtype of type 'Error' in type cast`

Here my code:

```
var hubConnection;
String mobileSession;

Future<void> createSignalRConnection() async {
  hubConnection =
      new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(GLOBAL_BACKEND_SESSION_NEW).build();
  await hubConnection.start();
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection successful");
  hubConnection.onclose((error) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection Closed");
    createSignalRConnection();
  });
}

Future<bool> sendParingCode(String pairingCode) async {
  final result = await hubConnection
      .invoke("RequestPairing", args: [mobileSession, pairingCode]);
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Pairing successful");
  return true;
}

void initSession() async {
  mobileSession = await hubConnection
      .invoke("InitSession");
  print(mobileSession);
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Session init successful");
}
```

I use it like this in a PageState:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createSignalRConnection();
    initSession();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should wait for `createSignalRConnection` to be completed before calling invoke method. Try this:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _asyncInitState();
}

Future<void> _asyncInitState() async {
    await createSignalRConnection();    // HERE: add await
    initSession();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use it with compute or something like that so that the app is not stuck?

Comment: This code should not stucks main event loop because _asyncInitState() called asynchronously without await.
Compute method spawns new isolate, I don't think you need to do that here. Use main isolate and it's event loop because connect and invoke operations are lightweight.
Useful article by the way - https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a